# which "process scheduling algorithm" Ubuntu 11.10 use

Tags: linux, algorithm

I want to know some OS algorithms about Ubuntu 11.10, but the information is so little. For example, I want to know which algorithm Ubuntu use with it's "process scheduling algorithm"?

Comment: Read the kernel source code, it's always a good idea.

Comment: That's too difficult for a Ubuntu beginner like me. Is there a easy  way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the inner workings of some product.

Answer (score 0):

Since kernel 2.6.23 (that would be as of Hardy 8.04 LTS) [Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) based on "Rotating Staircase Deadline". [Overview from kernel.org]: [2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt)

Comment: I got it, thanks. Are there some articles  about the operation system related algorithms. I want to learn.

Comment: This book is considered great http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/9332575770/geekdevinfo-20